# KML - Network Link Control 'Update' Usage

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-pro

I am having trouble getting a NetworkLinkControl KML command to work.

The drive.google.com URL matches `Network Link to Slot 2` and I am trying to use NetworkLinkControl to delete `kmlslot2`.

I know the `targetHref` tag works, because I have successfully been able to append a placemark under the `Network Link to Slot 2` directory, but have been unable to get the delete function to work.

Below is the KML text, along with an included picture of the KML that I am trying to modify.  I am using Google Earth Pro 7.1.8 on macOS for reference.

**I just realized I was confusing name and object id, but even after adding an object id ex: `<NetworkLink id="kmlslot2">` it still isn't working.

Any idea why this isn't working?

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
  <NetworkLinkControl>
    <Update>
      <targetHref>https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=**</targetHref>
      <Delete>
        <NetworkLink targetId="kmlslot2"/>
      </Delete>
    </Update>
  </NetworkLinkControl>
</kml>`

[image: KML to be modified]

Answer (score 1):

After 9 hours I finally figured it out, and hopefully nobody will have to repeat the troubleshooting I just did. The problem is described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kml-support-getting-started/gV3Hmd_xtNQ).

> This will give you "Security violation warnings"
>
> On page 51 of the KML 2.1 reference doc at the bottom of the page... its states that
>
> "the file containing the "NetworkLinkControl" must have been loaded by a network link. This is a key point.
>
> Therefore create a separate update network link which points to your "Network_link_control" file.
>
> Don't try and click on a link or load that file into Google Earth independently othwise you get the security violation warning. Its a very important mechanism which can get over looked very easily if your breezing over the docs!!!

Creating a local NetworkLink didn't work for me either, I had to upload my NetworkLinkControl.kml to the internet in order for it to run.  Even with error reporting turned on, I never got a message that indicated I had a security violation, until I tried to run NetworkLinkControl via a local network link.